# Copy Parts of a Dataframe into another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
user = users[1]
column_user=list(user)
p = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((50, 5)), dtype=str, columns=column_user)
p[:]=user[4:54]
print(p)
```

So p is just a dataframe filled with zeros and I want to copy certain rows of a user df into the first 50 rows of the p df.
But for some reason it sets every row before 4 to Nan.
Any Idea why the index of the df i want to copy to depends on the index of the copied df? Any idea how to fix this problem?

[image: output]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you directly create that dataframe:

```
pd.DataFrame(user[4:54].values, dtype=str, columns=column_user)
```

or just replace

```
p[:]=user[4:54]
```

with

```
p.iloc[:50]=user[4:54].values
```

Comment: I want to fill users, who have less then 50 rows with zeros.
But .values solved the problem.
Thank you very much.